# Installing external linux kernel module into /lib/modules/`uname -r`/ directory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile, linux-device-driver

I have a small USB driver kernel module, Now I want to install this module into running kernel directory i.e. (/lib/modules/`uname -r`/). Which should also updates modules.alias and modules.usbmap file.

Any script available to install the external kernel module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all:  
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules  

install:  
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules_install  

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Do "make" and "make install"

--- 5.2 INSTALL_MOD_DIR

```
External modules are by default installed to a directory under
/lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/extra/, but you may wish to
locate modules for a specific functionality in a separate
directory. For this purpose, use INSTALL_MOD_DIR to specify an
alternative name to "extra."

    $ make INSTALL_MOD_DIR=gandalf -C $KDIR \
           M=$PWD modules_install
    => Install directory: /lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/gandalf/
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the useful hint :).The command modules_install works fine for me :)